# Searching equidistant point from sets of points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I process lunar impact craters. At this stage each of them has about 16 points on their rim, they all have crater's ID in their attribute table (which has all points for all craters). Now I want to find equidistant point for each crater (set of points) to find their approximate center. This is for sure not best metod, but it's something I still want to finish to compare with others.

In ArcMap, is there a way, a tool, or maybe toolset to automaticaly create equidistant point from given sets of point?

[image: attribute table of points]

Comment: The spatial statistics tool Central Feature might be worth looking at https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p00000015000000 but you will need to iterate your crater ID as it considers all points equal. If you generate the Minimum Bounding Geometry https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003q000000 with group option CraterID you will get a set of polygons which you can gain the centroid of https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Feature_To_Point/00170000003m000000/ (advanced license required) does that help?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I think the central feature was enough, it has a "case" option where you can input a grouping field.

Comment: @MichaelStimson you pretty much solved it! Thanks a lot! Gonna try both methods

Comment: @Albert but doesn't Central Feature just identifies most central feature? In my case I need to create a new one, not determinate one from a set

Comment: @НиколайСлодарж Yes, I see that now. Actually what I'd do is to dissolve your points based on your grouping attribute and then run the feature to point tool which will give you the centroid.

Comment: If you have a working method please post an answer to this question, it's a little unusual but would have other practical uses, for the benefit of future users with similar problems it would be good to have an answer with screen grabs of the source and result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much answered in comments. Used Minimum Bounding Geometry with circle as a geometry, grouping by CraterID, first. Circle - because not all craters have perfect round rim, some of them intersect, so highest point of profile of crater is not always on rim; when using circle as geometry for MBD it allows to create polygons that cover all points with minumum sized sircle. Then used Feature to Point for each polygon, got points - their centers, then calculated coordinates in attribute table.